# personalizar aviso normal de html cuando un campo es requerido

Tags: html5, bootstrap

es posible modificar el aviso que viene por defecto de html??, estoy haciendo un formulario y necesito que un checkbox cuando le coloco el atributo required
me diga. "debes aceptar los terminos y condiciones". es posible eso??

```
                    <div class="form-group col-lg-12 col-xs-12 checkbox">
                        <label><input type="checkbox" name="" required>Acepto <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Terminos y Condiciones</a></label>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Valida con jquery y muestra la alerta con Pnoty por ejemplo

Comment: tambien puedes personalziarlo usando title: `<input title="Se necesita un nombre" type="text" name="nombre" required/>` pero esto funciona solo en Chrome

Comment: no me sirvio con la segunda opcion